# Trying to understand useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I try to load my article content from the server and display it on the page.

However, the content is stored in HTML format, so I need to tell the web is HTML instead of plain text.

Because I need to set the innerHTML, after the DOM has already mounted, otherwise my getElementById will be null.

I did find a workaround to solve it as the following code. However, my first load will fire handleContentLoaded twice. And, if I take off if statement

then handleContentLoaded won't be fired again when I click other View buttons for other articles, which means the content won't be updated.

Does anyone have any good approach?  Big, big thanks in advance!

[`My Code`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ecTg.png)
[`My Code`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8MQg.png)
[`The web looks like this`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTQLr.png)

**Edit**

For those who may have the same issue, you may check this article below.
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-static-html-with-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove `handleContentLoaded` and use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` on ItemContent tag

```
<ItemContent dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: articles.content  }} />
```

Comment: I tried it but got this problem **Can only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`**. Then, I changed to <div></div>, and it worked! Does this attribute mean changing whatever the content is to HTML? thank you.

Comment: @Summer Yes it will work same as innerHTML. please mark as answer and do upvote if this is helpful, thanks

Comment: Hi Jay, I find this article that mentioned the downside of using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, but it actually solves the problem, so I will still mark it as the answer.  https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-static-html-with-react